# AS3 Flash: getTime value to Date?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date, getdate

Is there a way to convert `date.getTime()` value to the Date? I mean, like this:

```
1377564829609 ----> Mon Aug 26 21:53:49 GMT-0300 2013
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var time:Number = 1377564829609;

var date:Date = new Date(time);
```

The Date class contructor

```
public function Date(yearOrTimevalue:Object, month:Number, date:Number = 1, hour:Number = 0, minute:Number = 0, second:Number = 0, millisecond:Number = 0)
```

And the adobe doc said like this

```
yearOrTimevalue:Object —  If other parameters are specified, this number represents 

a year (such as  1965);  otherwise, it represents a time value.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pan. I'll check it. I'll comment later.

Comment: And it's possible to do the opposite? Mon Aug 26 21:53:49 GMT-0300 2010 ------> 1377564829609. where the date is an old one (2010 in this case).

Comment: You may try Date's parse function, I think it should work. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#parse%28%29